# Add new tags with adding class using select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the multi-select dropdown in my project. In which the user can also add new tags.

**What I am trying:** When users add a new tag so add the class in this new tag with select2.
I am visited [document](https://select2.org/) but I didn't get any idea.

[image]

1. **One** is a selected tag from dropdown.
2. **Add custom tag with additional class** is the created by users.

Now I want new style in the tag added by the user(Add Custom Tag with Additional Class)

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a specific class to select2 drop element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692520/how-to-add-a-specific-class-to-select2-drop-element)

Comment: add a new class in the newly created tags by the user.